# How to throw exception in a .oct file in octave?

Tags: exception, error-handling, octave

I am currently developing `geotiff` reading and writing functions for octave using .oct files. I went through the octave documentation but could not find much on throwing exceptions. Does that mean I can throw exception the way I do it in C++ by just simply writing throw "error message"?

Comment: I your code now in shape and have you uploaded it to github as you said in 2015? Some others are interested in a Octave wrapper for libgeotiff

Comment: Please give us an update on what you did in geotiff, and link to your code. Andy's answer looks good to accept too.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways, admittedly they are documented in two utterly separate places, not cross-linked/cross-referenced, which makes no sense, and if you didn't know the function/keyword you wouldn't find them:

- **`error()`** raises an error, which stops the program. See [12.1 Raising Errors](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.2.1/Raising-Errors.html).

  `error("[%s] Here be wyrms", pkgname)`
- **`assert()`** both tests the condition then raises the `error()` with a customizable message (so don't do `if (cond) ... error(...) ... endif`).
  See [B.1 Test Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.2.1/Test-Functions.html#assert).

  `% 1. Produce an error if the specified condition is zero (not met).`
  `assert (cond)`
  `assert (cond, errmsg)`
  `assert (cond, errmsg, …)`
  `assert (cond, msg_id, errmsg, …)`

  `% 2a. Produce an error if observed (expression) is not the same as expected (expression); Note that observed and expected can be scalars, vectors, matrices, strings, cell arrays, or structures.`
  `assert (observed, expected)`

  `% 2b. a version that includes a (typically floating-point) tolerance`
  `assert (observed, expected, tol)`
- See also the command **`fail()`**

Comment: +1, where would you have expected the crosslinks? If you can provide a changeset I'm glad to review and push it

Comment: @Andy The functions should be listed on page https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.0/Exception-and-Error-Handling-in-Oct_002dFiles.html#Exception-and-Error-Handling-in-Oct_002dFiles.

Comment: @Andy: I said above that `assert()` should be mentioned and cross-reference from `error()` docpage, and vice-versa. I no longer actively use Octave otherwise I would provide a changeset.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could just use something like

```
error ("mynewlib: Hello %s world!", "foo");
```

to signal errors which are catched and viewed.

(Personally I think such questions should really go to the GNU Octave mailing list where you'll find the core developers and octave-forge package maintainers).

I guess you want to build a wrapper around `libgeotiff`? Have a look at the octave-image package! Where do you host your code?

./examples/code/unwinddemo.cc might also be interesting for you. It shows how to use unwind_protect and define user error handlers.

http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/file/3b0a9a832360/examples/code/unwinddemo.cc

Perhaps your function should then be merged into the octave-forge mapping package: "http://sourceforge.net/p/octave/mapping/ci/default/tree/"

Comment: i am using gdal. right now I am using a pvt repo...will put in github once it is in shape..thanks

Comment: @Andy Re: your first paragraph "Personally I think such questions should really got to the GNU Octave mailing list where you'll find the core developers and octave-forge package maintainers.": As StackOverflow tries to be a single place for *all the good answers*, I see no reason to not document any potential answers to questions here, too. Mailing lists are generally more volatile and less searchable than SO.

Comment: @Andy but, really, any such discussion probably belongs in [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Thats what I was wondering. Is stackoverflow the last place to put your questions or the first place? Ofcourse I am talking about not so trivial questions.

Comment: @NielsAbildgaard I think that only. 1% of the Octave developers use StackOverflow, so if you have questions which concerns the Octave internals (in this case the C++ API) the chance to get an answer here is low or not representative. Also bugreport should go IMHO to the bugtracker where they got read and not to SO.

Comment: Andy, this is fodder for meta, but if 99% of octave users don't use SO as primary, that is in part a chicken-and-egg **because** there aren't many or high-quality octave answers on SO (let's fix that!) SO beats octave lists for someone like me who uses multiple languages daily, and wants to see/learn the equivalence between each, without subscribing to 20+ lists and drowning under the mail-volume. Also there are well-rehearsed reasons why the community-voted website format beats mailing-list at producing and rating quality answers, merging, tagging, community wiki, culling low-quality Q&A, etc

Comment: @smci I said 99% of octave developers doesn't use SO, not 99% of normal octave users. Are we agreed that, for example a question specific to an implementation detail or bug in Btrfs would get the right attetnion on their mailinglist rather than SO?

Comment: @Andy: there are two separate considerations: getting an answer, and promulgating the answer. In general it's ok to post here (can also post to list). I saw this as a generic user-level question, one that is badly served by the doc, per my answer. I had independently spent quite some time looking for similar answer.